# Spring message TTL does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, messaging, spring-amqp, ttl

I am using spring-amqp 1.5.2 and would like to publish message which can reside in the queue for at most 10 seconds:

I am setting the expiration to 10000 (10 seconds) for all my messages but the messages are still in the queue after 10 seconds. Here is my code snippet:

```
MessageProperties props = new MessageProperties();

props.setExpiration("10000");

Message message = new Message(event.toByteArray(), props); 
this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("my-exchange", "my-routing-key", message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `send()` instead of `convertAndSend()`.

Conversion is for sending some object that needs to be converted to a `Message`; you already have a `Message`.

**EDIT**

However, this was fixed in 1.1.0 [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-219) so that should not be the problem.

This works fine for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So45824146Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So45824146Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            MessageProperties props = new MessageProperties();
            props.setExpiration("5000");
            Message message = new Message("foo".getBytes(), props);
            template.convertAndSend("foo", message);
        };
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: How does that resolve the issues of the time to live? Does the 'convert' part,  when applied to an existing Message, strip out any properties that were previously set?

Comment: When using the `convertAndSend`, you are asking the template to wrap the object (which happens to be a message in your case) in a new message, which won't have your headers.

Comment: `convertAndSend` does a check for if the object passed in is a `Message` already and doens't wrap it. Using `send()` had no impact for me - the per-message expiration is still ignored by RabbitMQ.